# Bulk translate a single node

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Using the [Internationalization Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) I have configured multiple languages (all English, but different countries). We are using the languages to present variable data on pages but don't necessarily want to translate the body. For example, Canada and the US have different phone numbers and currency but the language is still English and the copy may or may not need to be changed.

For the most part a node is Language Neutral (und) but when we need a single translation for the node, we still need to create the remaining translations as well. This is a lot of extra clicks and we have to do this hundreds of times.

Is there a way to create all of the translations with the click of a button? I spent a good deal of time searching with no luck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Language Fallback Module stopped working, I created my own:

[Alternative Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/alternative_language)

> Allows a language to specify an alternative language so if a node
>   translation for a specific language does not exist, Drupal will try to
>   load the translation for the alternative language before throwing a
>   404.
>
> This module is useful if you have multiple languages and only one
>   language is typically translated. Rather than create all of the other
>   translations and maintain those, the non-translated languages can load
>   the node from the alternative language.

Answer (score 0):

The [Language Fallback Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_fallback) solved this for me. Rather than translate a dozen nodes, this module allows you to translate only those nodes that require it and have the others fallback to a default.